# How to check a grouped data set variables for limit breaches specific for the variable, group and subgroup

Tags: r

I am struggeling with grouped set of variables that I need to check for being compliant with min/max limits that are specific for the variable as well as the assigned group and subgroup.

The data set to be checkt looks something like that:

```
Fuel    Season  Variable 1  Variable 2  Variable 3
Type_1  S   NA  85.4    59.6
Type_2  W   96.8    85.2    86.6
Type_1  S   NA  85.3    59.5
Type_2  W   96.6    85.3    83.5
Type_2  S   NA  85.5    60.9
Type_2  W   95.5    85.3    88.9
Type_7  W   96.8    85.2    86.5
Type_8  S   NA  85.2    59.5
Type_1  W   97.5    85.4    89.2
Type_3  W   96.2    85.3    85.1
Type_2  S   NA  85.3    59.6
Type_1  W   97.1    85.3    88.9
Type_2  W   96.6    85.3    86.0
Type_1  S   NA  85.4    59.6
Type_2  W   96.6    85.4    82.9
Type_3  W   96.3    85.2    86.7
Type_1  W   96.8    85.1    89.2
```

The applied limit values depend on fuel type and season. Although the limits seem the same in this sample data set, they are not for the real one with further variables.

```
Fuel    Season  Limit Type  Variable 1  Variable 2  Variable 3
Type_1  S   min 94,6    84,5    43,8
Type_1  S   max 1000    1000    61,3
Type_1  W   min 94,6    84,5    43,8
Type_1  W   max 1000    1000    61,3
Type_2  S   min 94,6    84,5    43,8
Type_2  S   max 1000    1000    61,3
Type_2  W   min 94,6    84,5    43,8
Type_2  W   max 1000    1000    61,3
Type_3  S   min 97,6    87,5    43,8
Type_3  S   min 1000    1000    61,3
Type_3  W   max 97,6    87,5    43,8
Type_3  W   min 1000    1000    61,3
```

The output I would like to achieve would be a list/dataframe of limit breaches per variable grouped by Fuel and Season like:

```
Fuel    Season  Variable 1  Variable 2  Variable 3
Type_1  S   1   NA  NA
Type_1  W   NA  1   1
Type_2  S   NA  NA  NA
Type_2  W   NA  1   1
Type_3  S   1       NA
Type_3  W   2   1   1
```

I already tried different things starting with mapply/tapply over group_modify but can't get it to work. I'am quite certain a group specific loop combined with the mapply function should do, I just dont get it to work.
I'd be very greatful if one of you would help me out here.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.

Answer (score 0):

The main task, which is checking if the value of particular instance of `Variable 1` for example, is outside the limits, becomes trivial if you reshape your data

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
left_join(
  pivot_longer(data, starts_with("Variable")),
  pivot_wider(pivot_longer(limits, starts_with("Variable")),names_from="Limit Type", values_from="value")
) %>% 
  filter(value<min | value>max) %>% 
  count(Fuel, Season, name) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="name", values_from="n",names_sort=T)
```

Output:

```
  Fuel   Season `Variable 1` `Variable 2` `Variable 3`
  <chr>  <chr>         <int>        <int>        <int>
1 Type_1 W                NA           NA            3
2 Type_2 W                NA           NA            5
3 Type_3 W                 2            2            2
```

#### Update

If you want to ensure that all combinations of `Fuel`, `Season` and `Variable X` have a row/column, you can use `expand()` to create a data frame that has all combinations and use it in a wrapping left join

```
left_join(
  unique(data[,c(1,2)]) %>% expand(Fuel,Season, name =paste0("Variable ",c(1,2,3))),
  left_join(
    pivot_longer(data, starts_with("Variable")),
    pivot_wider(pivot_longer(limits, starts_with("Variable")),names_from="Limit Type", values_from="value")
  ) %>% 
    filter(value<min | value>max) %>% 
    count(Fuel, Season, name)
) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="name", values_from="n",names_sort=T)
```

Output:

```
   Fuel   Season `Variable 1` `Variable 2` `Variable 3`
   <chr>  <chr>         <int>        <int>        <int>
 1 Type_1 S                NA           NA           NA
 2 Type_1 W                NA           NA            3
 3 Type_2 S                NA           NA           NA
 4 Type_2 W                NA           NA            5
 5 Type_3 S                NA           NA           NA
 6 Type_3 W                 2            2            2
 7 Type_7 S                NA           NA           NA
 8 Type_7 W                NA           NA           NA
 9 Type_8 S                NA           NA           NA
10 Type_8 W                NA           NA           NA
```

Input:

```
data = structure(list(Fuel = c("Type_1", "Type_2", "Type_1", "Type_2", 
"Type_2", "Type_2", "Type_7", "Type_8", "Type_1", "Type_3", "Type_2", 
"Type_1", "Type_2", "Type_1", "Type_2", "Type_3", "Type_1"), 
    Season = c("S", "W", "S", "W", "S", "W", "W", "S", "W", "W", 
    "S", "W", "W", "S", "W", "W", "W"), `Variable 1` = c(NA, 
    96.8, NA, 96.6, NA, 95.5, 96.8, NA, 97.5, 96.2, NA, 97.1, 
    96.6, NA, 96.6, 96.3, 96.8), `Variable 2` = c(85.4, 85.2, 
    85.3, 85.3, 85.5, 85.3, 85.2, 85.2, 85.4, 85.3, 85.3, 85.3, 
    85.3, 85.4, 85.4, 85.2, 85.1), `Variable 3` = c(59.6, 86.6, 
    59.5, 83.5, 60.9, 88.9, 86.5, 59.5, 89.2, 85.1, 59.6, 88.9, 
    86, 59.6, 82.9, 86.7, 89.2)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -17L))

limits = structure(list(Fuel = c("Type_1", "Type_1", "Type_1", "Type_1", 
"Type_2", "Type_2", "Type_2", "Type_2", "Type_3", "Type_3", "Type_3", 
"Type_3"), Season = c("S", "S", "W", "W", "S", "S", "W", "W", 
"S", "S", "W", "W"), `Limit Type` = c("min", "max", "min", "max", 
"min", "max", "min", "max", "min", "max", "min", "max"), `Variable 1` = c(94.6, 
1000, 94.6, 1000, 94.6, 1000, 94.6, 1000, 97.6, 1000, 97.6, 1000
), `Variable 2` = c(84.5, 1000, 84.5, 1000, 84.5, 1000, 84.5, 
1000, 87.5, 1000, 87.5, 1000), `Variable 3` = c(43.8, 61.3, 43.8, 
61.3, 43.8, 61.3, 43.8, 61.3, 43.8, 61.3, 43.8, 61.3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thx @langtang for this promt answer. This does the job quite well with one little flaw. As an output I would need the full matrix of Fuel/Season variations by all variables even if there is a line or row of "all NAs" which is not given by this current code. Many thx.

Comment: one way to ensure this is to wrap my solution in another left join where we create a version of the dataset that has all combinations of Fuel, Season, and Variable - see edit